# Programatically activate page in aem

Tags: aem

I want to activate a page through code. Here is my code:
@Reference
Replicator replicator ;

```
replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, pagePath);
I am getting replicator as null. Can you please tell what needs to be done?
```

Comment: what is the context in which you are trying to use this?  is this in a service, a workflow or..?  what version of aem are you using?

Comment: I am using this in workflow process step. It is a java class. I am using AEM 6.5 version

Answer (score 1):

If your replicator is null maybe is not injected properly.

Try to check if you're using any Annotation to inject/reference it. In older versions @Reference should work, also in new versions I guess @OsgiService can work too.

I'll let you here an example of how Adobe use it.

[Adobe solution in GitHub.](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/reports/models/PageReplicationStatusModel.java)

Regards,

Comment: Another example can be found here too: https://github.com/cqsupport/replication-workflow-process